# How to place side-by-side Bootstrap images from the center and correctly resize them?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

My current view:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V068E.png)

How I want it to look:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwtZu.png)

How I wrote the Bootstrap code:

```html
<div id="logos" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="col-3">
    <a href="https://listen.tidal.com/album/107846023">
      <img class="img-fluid" id="tidal" src={tidal} alt=""></img>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <a href="https://geo.music.apple.com/us/album/_/1460176267?mt=1&app=music&at=1000lHKX">
      <img class="img-fluid" id="apple" src={apple} alt=""></img>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/6ITBoE1l1zPCtXKOTN12IC">
      <img class="img-fluid" id="spotify" src={spotify} alt=""></img>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <a href="https://www.pandora.com/artist/various-artists/love-hart-presents-hartfm-explicit/AL2V7Pb7xcg7p74">
      <img class="img-fluid" id="pandora" src={pandora} alt=""></img>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I re-size the images down by using something like "width: x%", then they just get spread out evenly over the page, not aligned in the middle like I want.

I tried adding left-margins to the pictures but that was just my eyeballing it to get to the middle, which seems like an incorrect way to do it.

UPDATE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv57J.png)

As you can see, I still need to re-size the right-most logo to actually make it bigger, and also there's still a bit of space between the logos that I want to get rid of (should I just set margins by hand in that case?)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be [ex240](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11838398/ex240)? Your question is VERY similar to his, and the answer to this question is provided in his question.

Comment: Hey yeah so that question was answered but my problem right now is different, because while the Bootstrap grid here is correctly placing the elements in terms of dividing row length and the span is correct, that's not what I want. I want 4 elements to be placed in the center, fanning out like in the first picture, with respect to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a simple fix; try to change how many columns each image takes up to one so col-1 instead of col-3. Because when you change the width of the images now it changes them within the columns preset width parameters. If you need them even smaller then I would ditch the grid system for at least that row and do the width and centering by hand. Good luck and happy coding!

UPDATE:

The extra spacing around the Pandora logo might just be from that specific image. The one you picked might have a lot of white space in it. If not try to make that one col-2 that might possibly fix it if you want to stick to that image.

Here are some monotone logos for all of those services

- [Tidal](https://icon-library.net/images/tidal-icon-png/tidal-icon-png-7.jpg)
- [Itunes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dgkq.jpg)
- [Spotify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga5qV.jpg)
- [Pandora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOEFj.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried float:none and m-0?

Comment: You mean writing the class for the Row like this? class="row float-none m-0 justify-content-center align-items-center"

Comment: Yea, either that or i would go with what remington answered. Sometimes the grid system just goes up in flames and you actually need to do it by hand